# Configuration to deploy app to AppFog via Eclipse/STS

Tags: cloud, cloud-foundry, appfog

I am trying to deploy a Java spring app to AppFog from within STS with the cloudfoundry plugin.

I have been able to deploy the same app to what was the old CloudFoundry free hosting (but since taken over by Pivotal it is no longer available).

I have been looking around and reading some articles on how this should work but all seem to be at least a year old, and I am hitting errors.

I have been following: http://www.srccodes.com/p/article/17/deploy-to-appfog-paas-using-cloud-foundry-integration-plugin-of-eclipse-sts and am on step 4) - adding the AppFog url. I have tried a variety of URLs that I have seen across the web, and the only URL I have found that does not give me a 404 is: http://api.eu01.aws.af.com  - However, when I accept that and then return to enter account details and validate (using the normal login details I use for the AppFog site itself) it always fails to validate.

Has anyone successfully connected and deployed from within STS to AppFog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This didn't work with any of the URLs or username/passwords in the end, so I just resorted to managing deploy through the CLI (which is still pretty nice).